# Alteration required to gather the AVdate and color change

Tags: powershell

I have written a script that gathers the McAfee AVdate and creates an HTML report. It changes the color on the reportto red if the AV date is 2 days older than the current date. Otherwise the color should be green.

Ihe script below doesn't change the color, even if it is older than 2 days. The color always shows green.

Can anyone help me to understand why?

```
$AVDate = (Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\McAfee\AVEngine").AVDatDate

$AVDatDate = $AVDate

if($AVDatDate -lt [datetime]::Today.AddDays(-2)){

Add-Content $report "<tr>"
    Add-Content $report "<td bgcolor= 'White'  height='30' align=center><B>12</B></td>"
    Add-Content $report "<td bgcolor= 'White'  height='30' align=left><B>McAfee AVDate</B></td>"
    Add-Content $report "<td bgcolor= 'red'  height='30' align=left><B>$AVDatDate</B></td>"
Add-Content $report "</tr>"

}

else{

Add-Content $report "<tr>"
    Add-Content $report "<td bgcolor= 'White'  height='30' align=center><B>12</B></td>"
    Add-Content $report "<td bgcolor= 'White'  height='30' align=left><B>McAfee AVDate</B></td>"
    Add-Content $report "<td bgcolor= 'Aquamarine'  height='30' align=left><B>$AVDatDate</B></td>"
Add-Content $report "</tr>"

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
$AVDatDate = $AVDate
```

To

```
$AVDatDate = get-date $AVDate
```

I suspect it’s currently comparing a string to a date. This might not work, it depends on whether the registry value you pull is convertible to a date via get-date. If this doesn’t work you’ll need to use the parseexact method instead.